# Generic delegate contravariance compilation error

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, contravariance, variance

I'm using the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233060.aspx) examples for `variance in delegate`. But the following code is giving me a compilation error. Based on my understanding, it should accept the `First` as an argument. What am I doing wrong? The code sample.

```
SampleGenericDelegate<Second, First> secdel = AFirstRSecond;
secdel(new First()); //compilation error here.

public class First { }
public class Second : First { }
public delegate R SampleGenericDelegate<A, R>(A a);
public static Second AFirstRSecond(First first)
{ 
    return new Second(); 
}
```

Errors

```
Delegate 'ConsoleApplication1.SampleGenericDelegate<ConsoleApplication1.Second,
ConsoleApplication1.First>' has some invalid arguments

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ConsoleApplication1.First' to    
'ConsoleApplication1.Second'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`secdel` has an argument type of `Second`, so you need to pass an instance of that:

```
SampleGenericDelegate<Second, First> secdel = AFirstRSecond;
secdel(new Second());
```

Comment: Does it mean that the sample is wrong on MSDN? If that's the case then I'm confused with the `contravariance`.

Comment: @gmailuser - I can't see where the delegates are invoked in the MSDN document. The variance is only relevant when assigning `AFirstRSecond` to `secdel`. Your error is simply due to passing the wrong type into `secdel`. The same error would happen if you tried to pass `new First` to an `Action<Second>`.

Comment: I was trying to invoke the delegate. I thought I can pass the `First` in the argument. Is it possible to pass `first` with the current delegate declaration.

Comment: @gmailuser - The first type parameter of `SampleGenericDelegate` is the argument type and the second is the return type. `secdel` therefore takes a `Second` argument and returns a `First`.

Comment: @gmailuser: What you're trying is the moral equivalent of `List<string> lst; IEnumerable<string> es = lst; f(es.Count);`  The object is a `List<string>` and it is compatible with usage as `IEnumerable<string>`, but when using it as `IEnumerable<string>` you lose all the additional capability of `List<string>`.  Similarly with the delegate, the method accepts a parameter of type `First`, but when you use it as the delegate type, you lose the capability of the specific method, and can only use it according to the delegate's type.

Answer (score 0):

The first type in the generic definition is the type used for defining the parameter of the delegate, not the return type. Change your code as such and you should be good.

```
SampleGenericDelegate<First, Second> secdel = AFirstRSecond;
secdel(new First()); //compilation error here.

public class First { }
public class Second : First { }
public delegate R SampleGenericDelegate<A, R>(A a);
public static Second AFirstRSecond(First first)
{ 
    return new Second(); 
}
```